# Как вывести не более n записей в которых встречается одно и тоже слово

Tags: sql

Есть таблица

```
category    city     gender  id count
Furniture   London   Female  4  2
Furniture   London   Female  3  1
Furniture   London   Female  5  1
Furniture   London   Male  4  3
Furniture   London   Male  3  2
Furniture   London   Male  5  1
Furniture   NY   Female  5  2
Furniture   NY   Female  4  1
Furniture   NY   Male  3  3
Furniture   NY   Male  4  1
Furniture   NY   Male  5  1
Kitchen   London   Female  9  2
Kitchen   London   Female  8  1
Kitchen   London   Male  9  3
Kitchen   London   Male  8  1
Kitchen   London   Male  10  1
Kitchen   NY   Female  9  4
Kitchen   NY   Female  10  2
Kitchen   NY   Female  8  1
Kitchen   NY   Male  1  1
Kitchen   NY   Male  8  1
Kitchen   NY   Male  10  1
Sport   London   Female  7  2
Sport   London   Female  2  1
Sport   London   Female  6  1
Sport   London   Male  7  2
Sport   London   Male  6  1
Sport   NY   Female  2  2
Sport   NY   Female  6  2
Sport   NY   Male  7  3
```

Надо что бы было

```
Furniture   London   Female  4  2
Furniture   London   Female  3  1
Furniture   London   Male  4  3
Furniture   London   Male  3  2
Kitchen   London   Female  9  2
Kitchen   London   Female  8  1
Kitchen   London   Male  9  3
Kitchen   London   Male  8  1
Sport   London   Female  7  2
Sport   London   Female  2  1
Sport   London   Male  7  2
Sport   London   Male  6  1
```

То есть по две записи на индивидуальный город и пол

Comment: Попробуй так: SELECT DISTINCT fFurniture, top2.fGorod, top2.fSex, fNum1, fNum2  FROM db LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 2 fGorod, fSex WHERE fGorod="London" AND fSex="Female" UNION SELECT TOP 2 fGorod, fSex WHERE fGorod="London" AND fSex="Male" ) AS top2 WHERE fGorod="London"

Comment: Здесь можете подобрать вариант в зависимости от СУБД: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php

Comment: Укажите метку конкретной СУБД...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [аналитическими функциями](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql):

```
select category, city, gender, id, count/*, rn*/
from (select
        category, city, gender, id, count,
        row_number() over(partition by category order by category, city, gender) as rn
      from mytable) as v
where rn <= 4;
```

[Тест на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb19b/11)